# Docker set up - cannot run hello-world

Tags: ios, proxy, docker

This is the first time i am trying to set up docker. I have followed the instructions, now i can see the docker machine running..  (i am on a mac, yosemite 10.10.5)

```
docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   URL          STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.9.1



docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

ran the following to bypass proxy...

```
eval $(docker-machine env --no-proxy default)
```

still the following fails, what could be wrong?

```
docker run hello-world
```

Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy.

Comment: Did you try without `--no-proxy`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your docker host cant access the internet, to verify, try 
docker-machine ssh default

And run 
dig Google.com
And see if you get some Google ips , if not you will need to check your virtual machine network settings,

open virtual box 
Stop the default vm
Go settings--->network
Make sure it's set to bridge or nat
Start the machine 
docker-machine start default
eval $(docker-machine env default) 
And try again

Comment: Jay first thanks for the response.

i could run dig google and got the ip back, but not from the docker shell (after ssh to docker machine). i got a dig not found in there.

verified the network settings, it is attached to NAT. there were two adapters, one is attached to NAT and one is "host-only adapter".

Comment: Ok, that's fine, you're using boot2docker which doesn't have dig. can you disable the adapter that's "host-only", and change the NAT one to bridged adapter, this will get you an ip from the same pool as your Mac.

Comment: after i did that and run docker-machine ls, i see this

    docker-machine ls
    NAME      ACTIVE   URL          STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER ERRORS
    default   *        virtualbox   Running                 Unknown   Something went wrong running an SSH command!
    command : ip addr show dev eth1
    err     : exit status 255
    output  :

Answer (score 0):

Set your docker proxy:

Edit your `/etc/default/docker` file

```
sudo vim /etc/default/docker
```

Add this entry at bottom:

```
export http_proxy="http://PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT"
export https_proxy="https://PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT"
```

Restart the docker service by using the below command:

```
sudo service docker restart
```